# Comments compared to string in python

Tags: python

I am just new to python.
as i know in python multi-line comments are made like this

```
"""
this is a comments
"""
```

but consider this code

```
somevariable="""this is a variable"""
print somevariable
```

it prints ***this is a variable***
are comments and strings are same in python or they are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one isn't a comment, it's a string. But since you're not *doing* anything with that string (printing it, assigning it to a variable etc.) all the interpreter does is say "Yup, that's a string alright!" and ignore it entirely. Effectively making it the same as a comment, since it's an arbitrary bunch of text that's ignored by the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

There are no multi-line comments in Python. They're both just strings. The former is typically used as a docstring and will be associated with the function/class/module, while the other gets assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same

It is called a docstring
You can find more information about this type of string here:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings/

Answer (score 2):

> are comments and strings the same in python?

Strictly speaking, they are **not** the same.  But in your question, what you refer to as "a comment" is actually a string.  A comment is everything appearing in the same line after the `#` character.

a.py:

```
"""
comment1
"""
# comment2
```

Now:

```
% strings a.pyc | grep comment
comment1
```

As you can see, `comment2` is not part of the compiled byte code, while `comment1` is -- because it's not a comment, it's a string.

As others pointed out, the string is considered a `docstring`. `docstring`s are conventionally used for documenting your code, while comments are used, well, for commenting, and are not included in the documentation.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the detail that docstrings are included in bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. It is a convention to include a comment string as the first statement of the function or a class.

See [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet is not a comment. It is a string. Comments in Python are prefixed by the `#` character.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> somevariable="""
... this is not a comment
... """
>>> print(somevariable)

this is not a comment
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes through docstrings.

This is actually not a comment, but a way to make a string with multiple lines:

```
>>> """This is a string
... with line breaks"""
'This is a string\nwith line breaks'
```

The same notation is used in classes and functions to document them:

```
>>> def my_function():
...     """This function does stupid things."""
...     return 1/0
...
>>> my_function.__doc__
'This function does stupid things.'
>>> my_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in my_function
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

So your code:

```
somevariable = """this is a variable"""
```

is really just equal to:

```
somevariable = "this is a variable"
```